# Is there a way to ensure that my jaxb elements are set before the attributes when using inheritance?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class (ChildClass) that extends ParentClass. When unmarshalling, I am getting an exception from setPropFromElementList() that the value I am passing in does not exist in the list, even though it does exist in the list. I believe the problem is caused by JAXB trying to set the the attribute of the parent before setting the elements of the child.

I saw various blog posts and questions that suggested making the parent class Transient and then using propOrder on the child class (including the elements from the parent class as well). This didn't help me - I got an IllegalAnnotationException.

Any ideas? (Sample code is below - it's not the *exact* code that I used, so I'm not 100% sure it will compile. It does, however, show what I did in my real code.)

ParentClass.java

```
@XmlTransient //on the entire class - not shown here

private String propFromElementList

@XmlAttribute
String getPropFromElementList() {
    return this.propFromElementList;
}

void setPropFromElementList(String value) {
    checkThatValueIsInList(value);
    this.propFromElementList = value;
}

protected abstract void checkThatValueIsInList(String value);
```

ChildClass.java extends ParentClass

@XmlType(propOrder={ "list", "propFromElementList" })

```
private String[] list;

@XmlElement
public String[] getList() {
    return this.list;
}

public void setList(final String... list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
protected void checkThatValueIsInList(String value) {
    //search for String and throw RuntimeException if not found
}
```

XML

```
<child propFromElementList="A">
    <list>A B C D</list>
</child>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> Is there a way to ensure that my jaxb elements are set before the attributes when using inheritance?

You cannot control the order in which a [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation populates the domain model.  A JAXB impl will most like populate the object model as it performs a depth first traversal of the XML document during the unmarshal operation.  This means that attributes will normally be processed before any child elements which appears to be what is causing the problems in your use case.

You may want to consider moving the validation logic outside the `setPropFromElementList` method and put it in an `afterUnmarshal` method.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The `propOrder` setting on the `@XmlType` is only used when marshalling.  You can not include properties mapped with @XmlAttribute in the `propOrder` on `@XmlType`.  Since you have:

```
@XmlAttribute
String getPropFromElementList() {
    return this.propFromElementList;
}
```

Then `propFromElementList` can not appear in the `propOrder` which is only for non-attribute nodes.

Comment: so is there any way to make sure that the elements are set before the attributes?